# How to combine 2 list based on a common key value in Ansible Jinja2

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x

I am trying to combine a particular value into a list based on a common key(organizationId) value from a JSON array. Here i am using a Jinja template to create a Json file that will be used for further processing. So here **sample.json** is the JSON file from where the **test.j2**(Jinja template) will be fetching the values to make a final JSON(mentioned below as Expected output)

**Sample.json**

```
[
    {
       
        "id": "111222333444627213",
        "organizationId": "111222333444624074"
        
    },
    {
        
        "id": "111222333444627214",
        "organizationId": "111222333444624074"
    },
    {
        
        "id": "111222333444627216",
        "organizationId": "111222333444624074"
    },
    {
        "id": "111222333444627217",
        "organizationId": "12345678"
    }
]
```

**test.j2(Jinja)**

```
[
  {% for dict_item in sample.json %}
{
   "orgid":"{{dict_item['organizationId']}}",
   "objectIds":[ 
       "{{ dict_item['id']}}"
   ]
}{% if not loop.last %},
  {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
]
```

**Expected Output**

```
[
  {
   "orgid":"111222333444624074",
   "objectIds":[ 
       "111222333444627213",
       "111222333444627214",
       "111222333444627216",
   ]
},
    {
   "orgid":"12345678",
   "objectIds":[ 
       "111222333444627217" 
   ]
} 
 ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jinja2 is not needed. Instead, iterate the list created by the filter [*groupby*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.groupby). For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        output: "{{ output|d([]) + [{'orgid': item.0,
                                     'objectIds': item.1|
                                                  map(attribute='id')|
                                                  list}] }}"
      loop: "{{ sample.json|groupby('organizationId') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  output:
  - objectIds:
    - '111222333444627213'
    - '111222333444627214'
    - '111222333444627216'
    orgid: '111222333444624074'
  - objectIds:
    - '111222333444627217'
    orgid: '12345678'
```